# array_unique on JSON objects

Tags: php, json

```
$accountData                    = json_decode(file_get_contents($filetxt_1), true);
$newdata['id']                  = $uvon;
$newdata['wallet_address']      = $walletaddress;
$newdata['timestamp']           = time();
$accountData[]         = $newdata;
$array = array_values(array_unique( $accountData, SORT_REGULAR));
file_put_contents($filetxt_1, json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Every time this PHP script is triggered by a $_POST, it is supposed to add a new JSON object to a file on the server. This works fine, except I need those objects to remain unique. I am attempting to achieve this with the *array_unique* and *array_values* functions.

After entering two sets of data containing a matching value, the output is this:

```
[
  {
      "id": "111.222.333.44",
      "wallet_address": "0x34c957891d19c88bc11e56c4ad6b1a65f09fda92",
      "timestamp": 1522101535
  },
  {
      "id": "111.222.333.44",
      "wallet_address": "0x3b958949efcc8362dd05179cce8eb5e16befebda",
      "timestamp": 1522101581
  }
]
```

The id's match, so the second object is not supposed to be in the file. Only if the id,wallet_address, and timecode are unique should the data be appended to the file.

Comment: checking only if the  `id` exist can solve your issue or do you have to check also `wallet_address`?

Comment: Both wallet address and ID have to remain unique for this application.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the `$uvon` is already present in the `id` values by getting all `id` values (using [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column)), and check if the value is present or not, before to update the JSON file (and the same for `wallet_address`):

```
$accountData = json_decode(file_get_contents($filetxt_1), true);
$ids = array_column($accountData, 'id');
$was = array_column($accountData, 'wallet_address');
if (!in_array($uvon, $ids) && !in_array($walletaddress, $was)) {
    $newdata['id']                  = $uvon;
    $newdata['wallet_address']      = $walletaddress;
    $newdata['timestamp']           = time();
    $accountData[]         = $newdata;
    file_put_contents($filetxt_1, json_encode($accountData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

---

The function [`array_unique()`](https://php.net/array_unique) can only reduce an array of "not-complex" values. Ex:

```
$array = [2,3,4,5,5,5,6,"foo","bar","foo"];
$array = array_unique($array);
```

Then `$array` will contains `[2,3,4,5,6,"foo","bar]`.

Comment: @CharlesRaiser You're welcome :) Don't forget to close your question if an answer solves your problem. Thanks :) See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235